# Do I need to play the previous games?

Tags: xbox-360, darksiders-2, darksiders

Darksiders II is out for free on XboxLive. Do I need to play Darksiders to understand whats going on? Or is the game completely different to the first?

Comment: The Darksiders II story is parallel to Darksiders I.
Maybe this helps you out: [link](http://darksidersdungeon.net/2012/04/is-darksiders-ii-really-a-parallel-story-or-a-prequel/)

Comment: Basically: no. Darksiders 1 is like what The Hobbit is to the Lord of the Rings series.

Comment: @Ben Far from that actually. The Hobbit is a prequel, explaining how the ring came to Bilbo. Darksiders 1 and 2 are parallel stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there a ton of references to the first game in the second one, there is no information from game 1 that you need to understand game 2. You play with a different horseman (death) and your quest is about finding out wtf happened to war (the horseman from 1). I would recommend playing the first one first, because it's awesome and it will give you better incentive to play through 2, but it's not necessary.

Here is a better explanation, but with spoilers:

> In Darksiders 1 you play as War and you get screwed over by the council that is supposed to keep the balance between heaven and hell. In part 2 you play as Death to find out what happened. The stories are parallel as @Jeykey mentioned, so you are gonna see some things from a different perspective that you already saw in the first game.